# How get mouse pointer on focus out for ckeditor

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

How get mouse pointer on focus out for ckeditor. suppose hello hi there was type in ckeditor. after focus out from ckeditor how can I determine where was mouse pointer(cursor)

Comment: Have you tried anything? Can you provide a simple demo?

Comment: I have done a lot search on this. I am unable to find anything which will help me to determine cursor position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By lot of search I have found this code which is working
        value = value.trim();
        CKEDITOR.instances['content'].insertText(value);